# bash: mv within for loop just recites usage

Tags: bash

Let's say I am trying to move files from the form "aa -- bb.pdf" to "bb -- aa.pdf".

The obvious way to do it is this:

```
for f in *;
do 
mv $f $(echo "$f" | sed -E 's/(.\*) -- (.\*)(\..\*)/\2 -- \1\3/'); 
done
```

I'd need to add single quotes around some of the arguments, since there are spaces inside the various arguments which wouldn't get picked up correctly, so it should actually look a little more like this:

```
for f in *; 
do 
    $(echo mv "'"$f"'" "'"$(echo "$f" | sed -E 's/(.\*) -- (.\*)(\..\*)/\2 -- \1\3/')"'");
done
```

But any way I do this, all I get is the standard usage recital for mv:
usage: `mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target`
etc.

When I output this to the screen, it looks great:

```
mv 'aa -- bb.pdf' 'bb -- aa.pdf'
```

But no matter what variation I try on this, it just recites usage (presumably telling me something is wrong with my syntax), and I can't figure out why.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a bash implementation:

```
re="(.+) -- (.+)([.].+)"
for f in *; do
    if [[ $f =~ $re ]]; then 
        newf="${BASH_REMATCH[2]} -- ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
        mv -- "$f" "$newf"
    fi
done
```

The reason for your error is likely the `--` which tells `mv` "end of options". Adding an additional `--` prior to the filenames should resolve the issue.

Comment: Spectacular.:(  I think the -- was actually impossible to shield, as it was buried at certain levels in my example and couldn't be escaped at the top-most level.  But thanks SO much for your help!  Worked perfectly.  Would have just beat my head against this all night.:)

Comment: @sstrasburg Happy to help. Don't forget to accept the answer if it resolved your issue.